# Is this correct usage of hook_node_view()?

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

```
hook_node_view_alter(&$vars, $hook) {

  global $base_url;

  if($vars['#node']->status == 0) {
    header('Location: '.$base_url.'/?errCode');
  }
}
```

Simple hook to redirect unpublished nodes to prevent 404s (this is just a proof of concept).

Factor 1: There is already existing unpublished pages that have redirects (via the Redirect Module from Drupal Core) - this shouldn't affect that.

This is placed in my theme/template.php file but I'm not confident that this hook is best suited (although it works). Is there a lower level menu router hook which I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a lower level menu router hook which I can use?

Yes, there is - you would need to use `hook_menu_alter()` to achieve this. Here's the code you should use:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = 'YOUR_MODULE_node_page_handler';
}

function YOUR_MODULE_node_page_handler($node) {
  // If the node is unpublished, redirect the user.
  //
  // Note: I would recommend adding an extra check so administrators and
  // users who can manage the nodes are not redirected. This way, they can
  // work with unpublished nodes.
  //
  // This is what you would use instead in that case:
  // if ($node->status == NODE_NOT_PUBLISHED && !user_access('administer nodes')) {
  //
  // This will work for ALL users on the site, including the administrators.
  if ($node->status == NODE_NOT_PUBLISHED) {
    drupal_goto('<front>', array('query' => array('errCode' => 1)));
  }

  // Let the core node handler serve the request otherwise.
  return node_page_view($node);
}
```

Notes:

1. You should do this through a custom module instead of the theme.
2. Bear in mind that this might interfere with functionality of other modules, as well as workflows. See my comments and alternative version of the code.
3. Use `drupal_goto()` for redirection instead of setting the location in header.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will try this. Part of the confusion for me is the labelling of `menu` for routing items, thanks for the answer Aram.
(And I will use a module :-) ).

Comment: $node-> status on the frontend only returns 0 or 1 I think btw. NODE_UNPUBLISHED has only appeared for me as part of hook_node_update().

Please update your example you have a chance Aram. Thank you again!

Comment: I updated the answer, but because I misspelled the name of the constant - it should be `NODE_NOT_PUBLISHED` instead. It's best practice to use that instead of 0/1. Let me know if this makes sense.